# CSS List style with start and separator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a ordered list. I would like to give the initial number to 6. I've used `<ol start="4">`. It is working fine. Later, I convert this list to some other format, so I changed the type attribute as `<ol type="A">` or whatever format I need.

Now I want to change the separator (by default dot(.)) to ).

Ex:

```
<ol start="4" type="A"></ol>

D._____
E._____
F._____
```

to

```
<ol start="4" type="A"></ol>

D)_____
E)_____
F)_____
```

By using the css

```
ol{
counter-reset: item;
}  
ol > li {
display: block;
}
ol > li:before {
content:counters(item) ")";
counter-increment: item
}
```

but it resets the counter value and give result as

```
1)_____
2)_____
3)_____
```

So what I need is to use the counter and type values to define the separator

For example:

If, `<ol start="4" type="A"></ol>`
the result should be

```
D)_____
E)_____
F)_____
```

If, `<ol start="4" type="i"></ol>`
the result should be

```
 iv)_____
  v)_____
 vi)_____
```

etc..
How to change the css to get the result as what I mentioned above? Javascript and Jquery Solution is also acceptable. Can someone help me please.

```
counter-reset: item 3; // working
counter-reset: item attr(start); // not working
```

So, I need to get the integer value from the start attribute

Comment: I don't think this is possible with CSS

Comment: Then How to do that??

Comment: You can replace the default dot with an image, so you could make an image of a bracket and place that one in as image

Answer (score 2):

Try like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d8eYN/1/)**

**CSS:**

```
ol.c {list-style-type:upper-roman;}
ol.d {list-style-type:lower-alpha;}
li{position: relative;}
li:before{position: absolute; left: -13px; content: ')'; background:white;}
```

**Output will be like this:**

```
vi) Test

vii) Test

viii) Test
```

Updated Fiddle **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d8eYN/4/)**

**CSS:**

```
ol {
    counter-reset: listCounter 4;
    list-style-type:none;
}
ol.c li:before {
    content:"(" counter(listCounter, upper-roman)") ";
}
```

**Output will be like this:**

```
(vi) Test

(vii) Test

(viii) Test
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'll check this in all browsers

Comment: i checked in mozilla, chrome, ie latest versions.. its working fine

Comment: As per your answer, how to do `(vi)`

Comment: @ling.s Updated my demo according to your requirement

Comment: I already got this. but instead of `listCounter 4` i need to change the 4 from attribute value. I need something like `listCounter attr(start)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using CSS `counter`. Have a look at **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fubeyuju/1/edit)**.

```
ol{
counter-reset: heading 3;  
list-style-type:none;
}  
ol > li {
position:relative;
}
ol > li:before {
  position:absolute;
 counter-increment: heading  ;
 content: counter(heading, lower-alpha ) ")";  
  margin-left:-18px;
}
```

**Updated HTML version.**

```
ol > li {
position:relative;
}
ol > li:before {
 position:absolute;
 content: attr(start) ") ";
 margin-left:-11px;
 background:white; /*background color playing a trick by removing  bg color this dot `.` again appear*/
}
```

Comment: The 3 is a default value? As per your solution, I need to change it every time. This is not fine.I need to get it from the attribute start

Comment: @ling.s do you need to remove the `.` also?

Comment: check my updated DEMO. by far I can reach with this solution.

Comment: It doesn't remove the dot symbol

Comment: only trick is too add a background color on `pseudo element`. are you using background color white or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

You could make an image of a )
then apply this css:

```
ul.li {
list-style-image: url('url/to/image.png');
}
```